# JAVA checking two numbers digit are the same

Tags: java

hi I am trying to solve Udemy exercise:
Write a method named hasSharedDigit with two parameters of type int.

Each number should be within the range of 10 (inclusive) - 99 (inclusive). If one of the numbers is not within the range, the method should return false.

The method should return true if there is a digit that appears in both numbers, such as 2 in 12 and 23; otherwise, the method should return false.

I am keep getting true while hasSharedDigit(9,99) I cant discover why..

```
public class SharedDigit {
public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int number1, int number2){
    
    if((number1 <10 || number1 >99) && (number2 <10 || number2 >99)) {
        return false;
    } 
    
    int numberOneFirstDigit = number1/10;
    int numberTwoFirstDigit = number2/10;
    int numberOneLastDigit = number1%10;
    int numberTwoLastDigit = number2%10;
    
    if(numberOneFirstDigit == numberTwoFirstDigit || numberOneFirstDigit == numberTwoLastDigit || numberOneLastDigit == numberTwoLastDigit) {
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ```(number1 <10 || number1 >99) && (number2 <10 || number2 >99)```

This condition returns true only if both numbers are invalid.

Comment: Quite a few mistakes there, first of all, the check should have an || instead of && because the method should return false if either number does not fall in the range.

Comment: Unrelated: just for the fun of it: dont limit yourself to their assignment. You see, the fact that you know that both parameters have two digits makes the assignment much easier. Ask yourself how you could solve this if the only restriction would be that both numbers are > 0 for example ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> If one of the numbers is not within the range, the method should
> return false.

Replace

```
if((number1 <10 || number1 >99) && (number2 <10 || number2 >99))
```

with

```
if(number1 <10 || number1 >99 || number2 <10 || number2 >99)
```

Apart from this, you have missed `numberOneLastDigit == numberTwoFirstDigit` in the combination of conditions which are supposed to compare the digits i.e. the combination should be

```
if(
    numberOneFirstDigit == numberTwoFirstDigit || 
    numberOneFirstDigit == numberTwoLastDigit  || 
    numberOneLastDigit  == numberTwoFirstDigit || 
    numberOneLastDigit  == numberTwoLastDigit
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Treating numbers as text

The [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66794240/642706) and comments solved your direct problem. Just for fun, we can take an entirely different approach.

The idea here is to treat the numbers as text. In doing so, we can address each of your two business rules:

- *Each number should be within the range of 10 (inclusive) - 99 (inclusive).*

  - Numbers between 10 and 99 happen to have exactly two digits. One digit or 3+ digits means out-of-range.
- *if there is a digit that appears in both numbers*

  - By collecting into a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of each character in the string that is our first number, we have a distinct collection for which we can [get the intersection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) of the same for the second number’s string. If the intersection, the resulting modified `Set`, has a size over 0, then we know digits are shared.

To explain the code below… The `codePoints` method generates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), a sequence of `int` numbers, one for each code point number defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) for each character in our string that represents our input integer. The `boxed` call [converts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing) those `int` primitives into [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects. Adding those `Integer` objects to a `Set` automatically makes them distinct, weeding out automatically any duplicate digits.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4OvxlF).

```java
private boolean twoIntsAreInRangeAndShareDigits ( int n1 , int n2 )
{
    String n1String = Integer.toString( n1 );
    String n2String = Integer.toString( n2 );

    // Check for negative numbers, meaning out-of-range, not 10-99. 
    if ( n1String.concat( n2String ).contains( "-" ) ) { return false; } 

    // Check for exactly 2 digits, meaning within range, 10-99.
    if ( ( n1String.length() == 2 ) && ( n2String.length() == 2 ) )
    {   // Numbers are within range. 
        // Check for common digits.
        Set < Integer > n1CodePoints = n1String.codePoints().boxed().collect( Collectors.toSet() );
        Set < Integer > n2CodePoints = n2String.codePoints().boxed().collect( Collectors.toSet() );
        n1CodePoints.retainAll( n2CodePoints );
        boolean sharesDigit = ( n1CodePoints.size() > 0 );
        return sharesDigit;
    } 
    else  // Else 1 or 3+ digits mean numbers are out-of-range.
    { return false; }
}
```

I am not arguing that this approach is better, just interesting as a different way of thinking about the problem.

Comment: @matt Negative numbers flunk the first test, out of range, 10-99 inclusive positive.

Comment: also `-1` to `-9` ? I believe that `twoIntsAreInRangeAndShareDigits(-1, 11)` will return `true`; same for `(-1, -2)`

Comment: @user15244370 You got me. `( -1 , 11)` fails by reporting `true`. I will have to add an additional line to fix, but not as slick now. :-(  But thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comparison here. What you have is `f1 == f2 || f1 == l2 || l1 == l2` but what's missing it `l1 == f2`, e.g. 12 and 23 would return false with your code because

- 1 != 2 (`f1 == f2` fails)
- 1 != 3 (`f1 == l2` fails)
- 2 != 3 (`l1 == l2` fails)
- your code is missing the 2 == 2 (`l1 == f2`) so add `... || numberOneLastDigit == numberTwoFirstDigit` to the comparison condition.

As the others already stated, your check is also wrong as it requires *both* numbers to be out of range so if just one is, it doesn't return false.

To make it easier, try to turn the condition around so that both numbers *must* be in range:

```
if(!(number1 >= 10 && number1 <=99 && number2 >= 10 && number2 <= 99)) {
  return false;
}
```

Often it might also be easier to read and maintain the code if you'd "name" the conditions:

```
boolean n1InRange = number1 >= 10 && number1 <=99;
boolean n2InRange = number2 >= 10 && number2 <=99;

if( !(n1InRange && n2InRange) { ... }
//or
if( !n1InRange || !n2InRange ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution

```
public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int x, int y){
    
            if( (x < 10 ||  x > 99) || (y < 10 ||  y > 99)){
                return false;
            }
    
            int xFirst = x / 10;
            int yFirst = y / 10;
            int xLast = x % 10;
            int yLast = y % 10;
    
            if((xFirst == yFirst || xLast == yLast) || (xFirst == yLast || xLast == yFirst)){
                return true;
            } return false;
        }
```